# Symfony 5, EasyAdmin3 : Field ImageField, How not to delete?

Tags: php, symfony, imagefield, easyadmin

Excuse me for my English.

In a form I use the ImageField (esasyadmin 3) like this :

```
$img = ImageField::new('img')
->setBasePath('images)
->setUploadDir('public/images)
->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[name].[extension]')
->setRequired(false)
;
```

The goal is to choose an image from the “public/images” folder.
However, if I decide to change this image, it removes the image I had previously selected from the folder.
I don't want this behavior because my image can be used elsewhere.
How to prevent this deletion?
Have I chosen the right type of control?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "change this image"? Are you changing the image file, or are you changing trying to upload a different image to an img property?

Answer (score 2):

Again, sorry for the delay but i think it can be usefull to share something about this problem.

I had the same problem where i wanted to prevent the default image deletion process when a new image is uploaded. I tried many different methods and i finally figured out what was the problem.

First of all, you can override the default type of the image. Using the `setFormType` method, you can set the `ImageField` to a `FileUploadType` like the example bellow :

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
   {
      return [
         ...
         ImageField::new('image')
            ->setFormType(FileUploadType::class)
            ...
   }
```

Then, if you take a closer look at the `FileUploadType` on the `configureOptions` method, you will see some parameters that can be overrided.

```php
$resolver->setDefaults([
   'upload_dir' => $this->projectDir.'/public/uploads/files/',
   'upload_new' => $uploadNew,
   'upload_delete' => $uploadDelete,
   'upload_filename' => $uploadFilename,
   'upload_validate' => $uploadValidate,
   'download_path' => $downloadPath,
   'allow_add' => $allowAdd,
   'allow_delete' => true,
   'data_class' => $dataClass,
   'empty_data' => $emptyData,
   'multiple' => false,
   'required' => false,
   'error_bubbling' => false,
   'allow_file_upload' => true,
]);
```

The last you need to do is to override the default function for the `upload_delete` option. Now you just need to override this callable using the function `setFormTypeOption` like this :

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
   {
      return [
         ...
         ImageField::new('image')
            ->setFormType(FileUploadType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOption('allow_delete', false)
            ->setFormTypeOption('upload_delete', function(File $file) {})
            ...
   }
```

You can also set the `allow_delete` to `false` using the same method.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the delay but use this:

```
$img=ImageField::new('img')
    ->setBasePath('images')
    ->setUploadDir('public/images')
    ->setUploadedFileNamePattern("$name.[extension]")
    ->setRequired(false);
```